# PushKit on iOS: Allowed timeout for processing push notification and notifying the completion back

Tags: ios, pushkit

What is the allowed timeout for app to process VoIP push notifications in PKPushRegistry::didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload?

Is there a way to notify the completion back to OS if app completes the processing faster?

Comment: Similar question for a different reason: my app has an asynchronous boot process. Because of this, everything it does on launch has to be async. When I receive a remote VoIP push, I add a launch task to execute after the app boot has finished. However, it seems like iOS effectively pauses my app again after didReceiveIncomingPush, unless I explicitly block and wait for the app launch to finish. Moving the queue to a background queue and blocking on app launch works, but it's annoying that I have to do this.

Comment: I have a similar problem that, because the app needs to load a lot of data when launched before the PushKit notification is processed, sometimes the app could not be launched or receive the notification. This only happens on iOS 10. Is there a timeout for app to process PushKit notifications?